# How to use multiple instances of the same View Component and Javascript files in the same Razor Page?

Tags: javascript, razor-pages, asp.net-core-viewcomponent, .net-5

I have a razor page where I'm importing two or more view components of the same type/source into a razor page. The view component is essentially the same but each instance will load different values from the database depending on the drop selections on the form instance as well streaming events from a different source through SignalR

Because each view component essentially points to the same javascript file, I find that only the first loaded instance of this view component is operational.

I'm not sure how to configure razor so it sees each loaded view component as a separate instance, so I can treat each razor form in the view component as a separate instance. this issue will likely also affect the fact that I have a textarea that will be dynamically be updated by SignalR

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 p-0 m-0">
<div class="row justify-content-center h-100 pl-0">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("EventsMonitor")
        <script defer src="~/js/eventsmonitor-custom-scripts/eventsMonitor.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 pl-sm-3 pl-md-2 pt-3 pt-sm-3 pt-md-0">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("EventsMonitor")
        <script defer src="~/js/eventsmonitor-custom-scripts/eventsMonitor.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so this is how I worked it out:

First things first, we don't want to be loading the reference JavaScript file more than once per razor page, I believe the browser has some intelligence on this point but to tidy up the code in my original question, lets move the script down to underneath the razor code block:

Razor Page (that will show multiple instances of the same view component)

```
@model MyProject.Pages.EventsMonitor.ViewEventsModel
@{
}

<div class="container-fluid h-100 p-0 m-0">
    <div class="row justify-content-center h-100 pl-0">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("EventsMonitor")
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 pl-sm-3 pl-md-2 pt-3 pt-sm-3 pt-md-0">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync("EventsMonitor")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- By using 'defer' you are telling the parser not to execute
   it until the document had loaded thus avoiding the problem
   of the having to put it in the layout for proper execution.
   Defer is supported by chrome, safari, and ie(10+), ff(3.6+), o(15+) -->
<script defer src="~/js/eventsmonitor-custom-scripts/eventsMonitor.js"></script>
```

In the above, you'll see that we have referenced the

`@model MyProject.Pages.EventsMonitor.ViewEventsModel`

which is a new class I created for referencing an integer (Counter) that we will increment each time we load a new instance of the view component.

Next up we create a small public class:

```
namespace MyProject.Models.EventsMonitor
{
    public class EventsMonitorViewModel
    {
        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now within the ViewComponent.cs file, we modify the method that returns the view:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewComponents
{
    public class EventsMonitor : ViewComponent
    {
        [BindProperty] // Bind to the small class we created in previous step.
        public EventsMonitorViewModel EventsMonitorViewModel { get; set; }

        private static int _value = 0;

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke()
        {
            var EventsMonitorViewModel = new EventsMonitorViewModel
            {
                // See MS Link in notes for an increment function.
                Counter = Interlocked.Increment(ref _value)
            };

            return View(EventsMonitorViewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

The MS Guidance for incrementing is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-5.0

So in essence, each time we load a new instance of the same View Component, the Razor View is returned with the view model class that we bind to the razor page.

In my View Component Razor file (Default.cshtml file) we modify the Id's of each razor/html component that we will be interacting with using JavaScript. I'm not going to include the whole file, but a sample section of the razor form is shown below (these dropdown select boxes you can see in the image I showed in my original question):

```
@model WebApp_PLUGIN.Models.EventsMonitor.EventsMonitorViewModel

<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 1.5em">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <label class="control-label">Plugin Type</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="@("pluginTypeSelect"+Model.Counter)" onchange="pluginTypeSelect(this.id)">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="RS232Port">RS232 Port</option>
                    <option value="SmtpServer">SMTP Server</option>
                    <option value="TcpClient">TCP Client</option>
                    <option value="TcpServer">TCP Server</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm mt-sm-0 mt-3">
            <label class="control-label">Source</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="@("pluginSourceSelect"+Model.Counter)">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-danger" id="@("eventsMonitorMessageBarTop"+Model.Counter)"  style="white-space: pre-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above Razor code block, for each element Id, we add the counter variable to end of the Id string so as each instance of the View Component is loaded, each element will have a unique Id that increment upwards by +1.

So the result from all the above is when using JavaScript functions for logic of the UI components in razor, each view component and associated form elements will have a unique Id.
Sample JavaScript code below for testing:

```
function pluginTypeSelect(clicked_id) {

    // Each dropown select from each instance of the View Component will have a unique Id
    alert(clicked_id) 
}
```

In my testing, with reference to the screenshot in my original question, the dropdown select on the LHS View Component produced and Id "pluginTypeSelect1" and the RHS View Component produced and Id "pluginTypeSelect2"

The only part i hadn't addressed yet is the fact that the "Counter" variable will keep incrementing by +1 each time the Razor page is loaded, this isnt such an issue for me, but perhaps a very long running app it would be better to reset the integer back to zero again at some point so you don't end up with a long int. I'll think up a solution for this then update my answer.

Hopefully this helps others who come up against a similar conundrum...